# How to enable logged-in thumbnails for Safari Top Sites for Secure (HTTPS) Sites?

Tags: macos, safari

How do I allow Safari to generate logged-in thumbnails of HTTPS pages? Maybe there's a hidden setting for this?

Right now thumbnails of secure (HTTPS) pages are rendered without login data. For example, for private GitHub repo I see big "404" error. Most of my Top Sites thumbnails are login forms and error pages for various sites which makes "Top Sites" feature almost useless.

I'm aware that enabling logged-in thumbnails for Top Sites may have security/privacy implications.

Comment: I've tagged this OS X since I assume you are not using Safari on Windows or iOS. Please correct the tag and detail what version of Safari you are using if you still need an answer to this...

Comment: @bmike are you serious? ;)

Comment: Due to security matters this cannot be done.

Comment: @NEO Please submit that as an answer, and also back it up?  How do you know - can you produce documentation on this feature?